# Inno Setup - Checking if MS Access x64 Engine installed

Tags: vb.net, inno-setup

I have a setup script that doesn't seem to work the way I intended. I want to make my installer ONLY extract and install this Office x64 Engine if it is not already installed. I read through documentation and other questions that might help me out but still no luck. Here is my code in my .ISS script file:

```
[Files]
Source: ".\Kit3\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Check: AccessEngineNotInstalled

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#AccessEngine}"; Parameters: "/passive"; Check: AccessEngineNotInstalled
```

And here is the function I wrote to check if it is installed:

```
function AccessEngineNotInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0');
end;
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Thank you.

Comment: Should that registry key be stored under the 64-bit node ? Are you using 64-bit install mode (explicitly specified `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode` directive) ?

Comment: Here is the deal: We have a 32-bit version of Office installed. I am coding plugins for an application that is run in 64-bit, plugins are in VB.NET and the plugins also are communicating with an Access DB file. To do this in a 64-bit application I have to install the 64-bit engine for Access.

I am not sure if it is stored under the 64-bit node... and I don't think I am using 64-bit install mode, can you explain that? Thanks for the reply. @TLama

Comment: 64-bit mode means that things that are redirected (like registry and directories) goes into their 64-bit locations (e.g. `{sys}` constant maps to 64-bit system directory, `HKLM` key maps to 64-bit registry view). To enable the 64-bit mode, you would have to explicitly set the `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode` directive in your `[Setup]` section. It's a broader topic (I would refer you to help), but in general, if you're distributing a 64-bit application (that will be installed into 64-bit system locations), you want a 64-bit mode.

Comment: @TLama That did the trick. I just added under `[Setup]` the line `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64` and It worked! It now knows if it should extract/install the setup file or not. Thank you! Also please answer this question so you can get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added under `[Setup]` the line `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64` and It worked!